# Which of the following statements are correct regarding MLE

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

MLE here implies Maximum likelihood estimator.

Statements are :

> $1$. MLEs are always consistent
>
> $2$. MLEs are always unbiased
>
> $ 3$. MLEs follow normal distribution asymptotically
>
> $4$. MLEs need  not be a unique estimator

$1st$ is true and $2nd$ is false I know it I want to know reasoning behind $3$ and $4$ statement please give any example if you can.

Comment: I don't think any of these are true in complete generality. Some are true under certain conditions.

Comment: @angryavian Under which conditions first statement fails?

Comment: @Damandeep There are some sufficient conditions under which MLE is consistent or asymptotically normal. For examples of inconsistent MLE, see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2287314?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116725/example-of-an-inconsistent-maximum-likelihood-estimator). For countering #3, take the MLE of $\theta$ for a sample of size $n$ drawn from a $U(0,\theta)$ distribution....

Comment: ... Statement #4 is correct though, take [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84145/showing-that-the-maximum-likelihood-estimator-mle-exists-but-is-not-unique) simple example.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you for the correction; I misread #4 as "MLEs are unique" since the other three statements were stated in the affirmative.